# Using Adapter Design Pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, adapter

I was working on implementing an adapter design pattern to utilize the existing classes.  My problem is, the classes works almost same, but have different names and less functionalities on another.

For example, each **Work** class and **Homework** class has one function that does the same, which is **doWork()** and **doHomework()**.
I can link these to **doThis()** in **Task** interface.  But, **Work** class doesn't have **done()** function while **Homework** class has it.  How would I take care of this? Just no implementation? Are there any better approach?

```
class Task {
public:
  virtual int doThis() = 0;
  virtual bool done() = 0;
};

class Work {
public:
  Work();
  int doWork();
};

class Homework {
public:
  Homework();
  int doHomework();
  bool done();
  bool isDone;
};

class WorkAdapter : public Task, private Work {
public:
  WorkAdapter();
  int doThis() {
    return doWork();
  }
  virtual bool done() {
    // Is this okay not to implment this?
  }
};

class HomeworkAdapter : public Task, private Homework {
public:
  HomeworkAdapter();
  int doThis() {
    return doWork();
  }
  virtual bool done() {
    return isDone;
  }
};

int main() {

  Task *homework = new HomeworkAdapter();
  Task *work = new WorkAdapter();

  homework->doThis();
  bool isHomeworkDone = homework->done();

  work->doThis();
  bool isWorkDone = work->done();  // This would never be called in my implementation...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [adapter](http://www.oodesign.com/adapter-pattern.html) implementation using multiple inheritance (public for the target, private for the adaptee) is a valid approach.

Just take care of the the return type of the function:

```
class HomeworkAdapter : public Task, private Homework {
public:
  HomeworkAdapter() {}
  int doThis() override {  // make sure you override target member
    return doWork();       // and return value as expected
  }
  bool done() override {
    return isDone;
  }
};
```

*Hint: virtual doesn't need to be specified in the derived class.  Instead it's worth to use override, just to avoid subtle issues in case of non matching parameter or return types.*

When no feature is available for taking care of `done()` in the adaptee, you must emulate it. So its's not just about changing the name, but also ensuring similar behaviour:

```
class WorkAdapter : public Task, private Work {
  bool isdone;       // functionality to add
public:
  WorkAdapter() : isdone(false) {}
  int doThis() override {
    auto rc = doWork();
    isdone = true;    // once it's done, it's done ;-)
    return rc; 
  }
  bool done() override {
    return isdone;      // you must add this 
  }
};
```

Comment: First, thank you for replying.  I wasn't careful about return value.. I will edit it.  Would it be still worthy to do so if there are many "isdone" kind of things?

Comment: Some classes have a `done()` which could be more complex:  it could require several successive calls to achieve the done state.  Or the state could be a condition on some dynamic state (ex: oven heated over 200°). If you have many classes without `done()` you could think inheriting of a helper class,  or using a template to facotrize the repetitive function.