# How to use containers for template instances

Tags: c++, templates

I want to store the template instance using adapter pattern, it doesn't compile.
Can someone help me hear to compile.

```
class Shape_Adapter
{
    public:
        void draw() { Shape.draw() ; }
    private:
        T Shape;
};
class Circle 
{
    public:
        void draw() { cout << "Drawing Circle" << endl; }
};

class Square
{
    public:
        void draw() { cout << "Drawing Square" << endl; }
};


Shape_Adapter<Circle> cir;
Shape_Adapter<Square> sqr;

    cir.draw(); //Works
    sqr.draw(); // Works
    
    map<int, Shape_Adapter*> mapIdToShape; // But this fails
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Is `Shape_Adapter` a template? If so, it is not a type, and there is no such thing as `Shape_Adapter *`. You want to use inheritance and virtual functions. Make `Shape_Adapter` inherit a (non-template) class and store pointers to that class.

Answer (score 2):

You have several ways to handle that:

- traditional virtual way:

  ```
  struct IShape
  {
      virtual ~IShape() = default;
      virtual void draw() const = 0;
  };
  struct Circle : IShape
  {
      void draw() const override { std::cout << "Drawing Circle\n"; }
  };

  struct Square : IShape
  {
      void draw() const override { std::cout << "Drawing Square\n"; }
  };

  // Usage:
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IShape>> shapes;
  shapes.push_back(std::make_unique<Circle>());
  shapes.push_back(std::make_unique<Square>());
  for (auto& shape : shapes) {
      shape->draw();
  }
  ```

  [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a892a8a2dede846f)
- variant way:

  ```
  struct Circle
  {
      void draw() const { std::cout << "Drawing Circle\n"; }
  };

  struct Square
  {
      void draw() const { std::cout << "Drawing Square\n"; }
  };
  using VariantShape = std::variant<Circle, Square>;

  // Usage:
  std::vector<VariantShape> shapes{Circle(), Square()};
  for (auto& variantShape : shapes) {
      std::visit([](const auto& shape){ shape.draw(); }, variantShape);
  }
  ```

  [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4e99c3b762c84dd)
- type erasure:

  ```
  class Shape
  {
      struct IShape
      {
          virtual ~IShape() = default;
          virtual void draw() const = 0;
      };

      template <typename T>
      struct ShapeT : IShape
      {
          ShapeT(T shape) : shape(std::move(shape)) {}
          void draw() const override { shape.draw(); }
          T shape;
      };
  public:
      template <typename T,
                std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<Shape, std::decay_t<T>>, int> = 0>
      Shape(T&& t) :
          shape(std::make_unique<ShapeT<std::decay_t<T>>>(std::forward<T>(t))) {}

      void draw() const { shape->draw(); }
  private:
      std::unique_ptr<IShape> shape;
  };

  struct Circle
  {
      void draw() const { std::cout << "Drawing Circle\n"; }
  };

  struct Square
  {
      void draw() const { std::cout << "Drawing Square\n"; }
  };
  // Usage    
  std::vector<Shape> shapes;
  shapes.emplace_back(Circle());
  shapes.emplace_back(Square());
  for (auto& shape : shapes) {
      shape.draw();
  }
  ```

  [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3eb493530d902c7c)

Comment: Wouldn't  the first way be classic type erasure too (we erase type, reducing but not slicing it to `IShape`)? 3rd ways is some architectural pattern, I think, an adapter?

Comment: I wouldn't consider 1st way as type erasure (used types require inheritance, whereas 3rd way only requires to satisfy some traits).

Comment: I saw presentation about opaque types for 3rd way, they mention some pattern but none I remember match completely :-/

Comment: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IShape>>` I would argue that `std::unique_ptr<IShape>` or a raw pointer does that too, reducing "common traits" to the common static type `IShape` and its traits and to ability to call destructor because it's virtual. But yeah, I guess difference is in methodology of pure-OOP languages. There is also approach hat mixes those all and uses CRTP - curiously recurring template pattern, but it's a niche one.

Answer (score 0):

since `Shape_Adapter` is template you should initialize it with `Shape_Adapter<something>` so you cannot use `Shape_Adapter*` since it doesn't initialize so in order use `Shape_Adapter*` i suggest you to not use `Shape_Adapter` as template use it like inheritance and set functions to virtual functions and then override it in subclass you can easily achieve adapter pattern with inheritance rather than template class.

more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34212670/using-adapter-design-pattern) or [here](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/adapter/cpp/example)